# Why isn't move constructor invoked?

Tags: c++, move-constructor

Here is the code: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/f7731b48747c61a9

```
#include <iostream>

struct A{
    A(const A&){ std::cout << "A(const A&)" << std::endl;}
    A(const A&&){ std::cout << "A(const A&&)" << std::endl;}
    A(){ }
};

A foo(){
    return *new A;
}
int main()
{
    A a;
    A c(foo());
}
```

Since, I passed to the `c`'s constructor argument a temporary object, I expected the move constructor to be called. But the copy constructor was. Why?

Comment: I'm fairly sure "const r-value reference" (`const &&`)is nonsensical in the general sense. R-value reference handling is done to explicitly alter the argument passed (reducing it to an empty shell usually, taking all resources from it to populate a different object); if you don't modify it, then just accept a const l-value reference (`const &`) and be done with it.

Comment: [With -fno-elide-constructors added](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/7b7181af77a7c4ce)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since `foo` returns a *non-constant* rvalue, it cannot bind to the const-rvalue reference. The copy constructor is the only remaining viable overload.

A constructor that would be a better overload than the copy constructor would be:

```
A(A&&);
```

Additionally, either constructor (copy or move) may be elided under the rules of copy elision (e.g. [see here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12953129) or [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3663506).)

Comment: @stella I think the problem is with the *memory leak operator* `*new`, the compiler is not eliding copying that to the return value. Replace that with `return {};` and you won't see anything printed.

Comment: @stella: Added note on copy elision.